# Can anybody give me the code of titleforheaderinsection method's code to make my table devided in two section 

Tags: iphone

hiiiii,

i am a beginner for iphone and i want to make so much experience with iphone sdk codding...

Can anybody give me the code of titleforheaderinsection method's code to make my table devided in two section ...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
     return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"I am a title header: section %d", section];
}
```

From apple site:
http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDatasource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Thanks you 
and this is very helpfull for me 
hanks again

Comment: Maybe you could then check this answer as the correct answer.